# Robot Framework FOR loop

Tags: robotframework

I would like to save elements into a list, and then run a FOR loop to iterate through them.

I have tried the following:

```
*** Keywords ***
User Claims Tasks
    @{tasks}=    Get WebElements    ${claim}
    FOR    ${task}    IN    @{tasks}
        Click Element    ${task}    
        ${missing}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${miss}
        Run Keyword If    '${missing}' == 'True'    Click Element    ${miss}
        ${continue}=      Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${cont}
        Run Keyword If    '${continue}' == 'True'    Click Element    ${cont}
    END
```

However, this does not work. It runs once, and then I get the error:

```
20200911 13:40:19.734 : FAIL : IndexError: list index out of range
20200911 13:40:19.737 : INFO : ${relation uid} = ('FAIL', 'IndexError: list index out of range')
20200911 13:40:19.742 : INFO : Relation UID:('FAIL', 'IndexError: list index out of range')
20200911 13:40:19.744 : INFO : Client Information:, 
Ending test:
```

Any ideas on how to get this work?

Comment: Please share which line throws this error, and the return value of this line `@{tasks}=    Get WebElements    ${claim}` as it is shown in the log.html.

Comment: @{tasks} = [ <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="03200ec34b66c1a5cea7e41f7c1e9905", element="31b953c1-d1d5-47de-bae3-402a6cd57160")> | <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (ses...

Comment: The error occurs when it wants to click the second task (beginning of 2 iteration - click element task). It cannot click on the task because: element is not attached to the page document.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste it there, a comment is too short.

Comment: "element is not attached to the page document" means that when you get the webelements and store them for later use, when you actually want to use it, the page possibly has been already refreshed and the rest of the elements got `stale`, as they are connected to the page before the refresh. That is why the first element is OK, page is possibly changed when you handle the first element.

Comment: Try `Click Element    ${task.get_attribute("id")}` it will not use the stale webelement but will click on the element based on the ID. It will work if the page refresh or whatever is happening is not changing the ID of the tasks.

Comment: When you click on a task in the page, does it change? Like, the task list redraw? It looks so by the exception in the 3rd comment. If true, you have to rethink the logic - not to get all elements in the beginning - as they will change with interaction, but loop while there are still task elements, regetting them every time.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Well, it looks like it. I pasted the solution that worked for me in in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

```
*** Keywords ***
User Claims Tasks
    ${tasks}=    Get Element Count    ${claim}
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${tasks}
        ${present}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${claim}  
        Run Keyword If   '${present}' == 'True'    Click Element    ${claim}  
        ${missing}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${drm}
        Run Keyword If    '${missing}' == 'True'    Click Element    ${drm}
        ${continue}=      Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${cont}
        Run Keyword If    '${continue}' == 'True'  Click Element    ${cont}
    END
```